# SFML Crash using Clear function

Tags: c++, crash, sfml

I'm new to SFML and am currently reading through the documentation.  For some reason, however, my "program" crashes whenever I call the Clear() function.  My program code is as follows:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void HandleEvents(sf::RenderWindow &App)
{
    sf::Event Event;
    while (App.GetEvent(Event)) {
        if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            App.Close();
            exit(0);
        }
        if ((Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape)) {
            App.Close();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 640, 32), "SFML Graphics");
    App.SetFramerateLimit(60);      // cap the framerate at 60 FPS
    while (App.IsOpened()) {
        HandleEvents(App);      // handle events... duh
        App.Clear();      // When I remove this line, the program doesn't crash....
        App.Display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So do any SFML gurus have advice for me?  I've tried researching this problem but the only other person I've seen who tried to ask this had a broken link (because of the new SFML forums).

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SFML are you using? Did you download the binaries or are you compiling it yourself?

Comment: I had the exact same problem when using v1.99 (dev version, default on arch linux) This was fixed when I compiled the library from source. sfml 2.0rc is out now though, you should give it a shot http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php#2.0-rc